# Cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am faced with a very strange behaviour of Dagger 2. Maybe I just don't understand it.

So I have 2 components:

**`AppComponent:`**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {/*my modules*/})
public interface AppComponent extends AppGraph {

    @ForApplication Context getContext();

}
```

**`ActivityComponent:`**

```
@ForActivity
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = {ActivityModule.class})
public interface ActivityComponent extends AppComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity activity);

    @ForActivity
    BaseActivity getActivity();

}
```

**`ForApplication:`**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ForApplication {
}
```

**`ForActivity:`**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ForActivity {
}
```

And also, I have an **`ActivityModule`**, which has `provides` methods:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private final BaseActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @ForActivity
    @Provides
    public BaseActivity provideActivityContext(){
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    public ContextWrapper provideContextWrapper(){
        return new ContextWrapperImpl(activity);
    }

    @Provides
    public CustomNavigator provideMakeDepositNavigator(){
        return new CustomNavigatorImpl(activity);
    }
}
```

So, when I inject `ContextWrapper` into my activity, I get no errors.

But when I inject `CustomNavigatorImpl`, I get the error:

> CustomNavigator cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method. Dagger 2

These 2 interfaces are the same. But `ContextWrapper` is injected, and `CustomNavigator` not

**`ContextWrapper`**:

```
public interface ContextWrapper {

    String getString(int resId);

    Context getContext();
}
```

**`MakeDepositNavigator:`**

```
public interface MakeDepositNavigator {

    void showSomething1();

    void showSomething2();

    void showSomething3();

    /*...*/
}
```

In application class I create `DaggerAppComponent`:

```
DaggerSdkAppComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(c))
                .build();
```

In `BaseActivity` I create `ActivityComponent`:

```
AppComponent component = ((HasComponent<AppComponent>) 
getApplicationContext())
                    .getComponent();
            mComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                    .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                    .appComponent(component)
                    .build();
```

Also, `BaseActivity` has a method:

```
@Override
public ActivityComponent getComponent() {
    return mComponent;
}
```

And in `CustomActivity`, which extends from `BaseActivity` I do:

```
getComponent().inject(this);
```

## UPDATED

**`Activity:`**

```
public class MakeDepositActivity extends BaseActivity{

/* some code */

    @Inject
    public MakeDepositNavigator makeDepositNavigator;

    @Inject
    public ContextWrapper cw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_deposit);
        getComponent().inject(this);

        /* some code */
    }


    /* some code */

}
```

Comment: Could you please also add the code of your activity with the fields you are trying to inject?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, I've updated the question, added activity with filed to the bottom

Comment: `MakeDepositNavigator` is the interface you provide in your module? (You messed up some of the renaming.) It looks alright...I would check if you just use the interface

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, yes, it's interface whic I provide from `ActivityModule`

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Idon't understand why I have no problems with `contextwrapper` it's interface too, but it injects without any problems

Comment: Well...the code *looks* fine. Try double checking your interfaces, imports, and scopes

Comment: MakeDepositNavigator & CustomNavigator are not the same. You provide a CustomNavigator when asking for a MakeDepositNavigator

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with testing.

```
@ForApplication Context getContext();
```

in `AppComponent` might not be accessible to sub-class `ActivityComponent` due to package accessibility (default accessibility).

I think that adding `public` as access modifier would solve your issue.